# For loop a single string value from a HDF5 file

Tags: python, for-loop, hdf5

I am trying to write a script that reads a specific hdf5 file that has a Field called `ElementAbundance`, which has araays fractional values for Chemical elements.

This is what I am doing, I open the hdf5 file, I make a list of the fields inside that file. If the file has the `ElementAbundance`, it will then check if the element I ask for in `field` is in the `elements` array. If it is in the array, I am then wanting to return the element I asked for as a single string.

I have checked elsewhere and the fields in `ElementAbundance` are

`elements = ['Carbon', 'Helium', 'Hydrogen', 'Iron', 'Magnesium', 'Neon', 'Nitrogen', 'Oxygen', 'Silicon']`

```
import h5py
from particleType import partTypeNum # This is another file that is unimportant in regards to my question

# Only necessary if gas (0) particle type

def loadElement(basePath,snapNum,partType,field=None):
    result = {}

    # This uses the above module to associate keys words with the letter 0    
    ptNum = partTypeNum(partType)
    gName = "PartType" + str(ptNum)

    # making sure fields is not a single element
    if isinstance(field, basestring):
        field = [field]

    # begin by opening the h5py file
    with h5py.File(snapPath(basePath,snapNum),'r') as f:

        # header = dict( f['Header'].attrs.items() )
        # nPart = getNumPart(header)

        # This creates a list for all the fields in the HDF5 file
        field_list = []
        for i in f[gName].keys():
            field_list.append(str(i))

        # This will check if the file has a "ElementAbundance" header
        for i in enumerate(field_list):
            # if the string is not inside the list, we raise an exception
            if "ElementAbundance" not in field_list:
                raise Exception("Particle type ["+str(ptNum)+"] does not have a field of elements")
            # If it is, we extract the chemical elements from inside the element abundance field.
            else:
                g = f[gName]['ElementAbundance'] # file contains elements
                elements = []
                for j in g.keys():
                    elements.append(str(j))


        # now for looping the lists values with their index
        for i,element in enumerate(elements):
            # if the element field is inside the elements list, we retrieve that element as a string
            if field == element:
                the_element = str(elements[i])
                return the_element
            # if their is a ElementAbundance field but the asked for field element is not in that list, raise and exception.
            else:
                raise Exception("Element type ["+str(field)+"] not found in element abundance list.")

        f.close()
    # testing to see if the above for loop returns a single string
    return the_element
```

Now I then test this out if it returns the string 'Hydrogen', but I am returned with the exception: `Exception: Element type [['Hydrogen']] not found in element abundance list.`

Which is weird since, because `Hydrogen` should be in the `elements` list I have made. Also, the raised exception should return `['Hydrogen']` not `[['Hydrogen']]`.

If their is any additional information I can add, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling the function as:

```
loadElement(basePath,snapNum,partType,field='Hydrogen')
```

Then 'Hydrogen' is turned into a single-item list in:

```
if isinstance(field, basestring):
        field = [field]
```

When you iterate the elements list, you're iterating strings and matching them with `['Hydrogen']` is which a list, so a match isn't found.